# How to make JQuery-AJAX request synchronous

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

How do i make an ajax request synchronous?

I have a form which needs to be submitted. But it needs to be submitted only when the user enters the correct password.

Here is the form code:

```
<form name="form" action="insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this);" >
```

And the jquery code for sending and checking password is this:

```
var ajaxSubmit = function(formE1) {

    var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: "false",
        url: "checkpass.php",
        data: "password="+password,
        success: function(html) {
            var arr=$.parseJSON(html);
            if(arr == "Successful") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However the form always submits, regardless of the value returned by the ajax request. I have checked everything else. The value of arr is coming out to be 'successful' when correct password is entered and works correctly vice versa too.

How do i make this request synchronous? as far as i can debug, the request is asynchronous so the form gets submitted before the request gets completed.

Code for checkpass.php

```
<?php 
require("includes/apptop.php");
require("classes/class_employee.php");
require("classes/class_employee_attendance.php");

$employee_password=$_POST['password']; 

$m=new employee();
$m->setbyid_employee(1);
$arr=$m->editdisplay_employee();

if($arr['employee_password'] == $employee_password)
{
$res="Successful";  
}
else
{
$res="Password not match";  
}

echo $res;
?>
```

**Update: The solution has been found.**

As pointed by Olaf Dietshche: The return value of `ajaxSubmit` is not the return value of the `success: function(){...}`. `ajaxSubmit` returns no value at all, which is equivalent to `undefined`, which in turn evaluates to `true`.

And that is the reason, why the form is always submitted and is independent of sending the request synchronous or not.

So, I set a variable to `1` inside success function upon successful. And checked its value out of success function, if it was `1` outside the success function, then I wrote `return true ... else return false`. And that worked.

**Updated working code:**

```
var ajaxsubmit=function(forme1) {
    var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());
    var test="0";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkpass.php",
        async: false,
        data: "password="+password,
        success: function(html) {
            if(html == "Successful") {
                test="1";
            } else {
                alert("Password incorrect. Please enter correct password.");
                test="0";
            }
        }
    });

    if(test=="1") {
        return true;
    } else if(test=="0") {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the dataType of your server response....json or html ??

Comment: you can call ajax by button click event and remove the form on submit and use form submit function on success event.

Comment: @bipen: the data type of my server response is html only

Comment: @Dinesh: yes i know it can be done that way. but i dont want to resort to that. any way by which this can be achieved by this way only?

Comment: thn why are u using `$.parseJSON(html);`...pareseJson takes a well-formed "JSON" string and returns the resulting JavaScript object... check ur firebug for what this gives `console.log(html)`

Comment: @bipen: my mistake. will just try and let you know

Comment: Have removed the parseJSON function and just checked value of html. still doesnt work. still the form gets submitted

Comment: add `return false` at the end of the ajaxSubmit function.. that should do.... can u post what u got in html .... or post `checkpass.php` .php

Comment: @bipen: Doesnt work. On entering correct password, form does not get submitted. Remains on the same page

Comment: yes.. i bet the problem is in your response ...can u post the  checkpass.php

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my post. Please check in a minute

Comment: check out my answer... :) :).. that should work

Comment: @bipen: still doesnt work :(

Comment: hey remove var arr=$.parseJSON(html); from code and use html==Successful in the code.bcoz you are not passing json value from php

Comment: @Dinesh: still doesnt work

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **async** Boolean
>   Default: true
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

So in your request, you must do `async: false` instead of `async: "false"`.

**Update**:

The return value of `ajaxSubmit` is *not* the return value of the `success: function(){...}`. `ajaxSubmit` returns no value at all, which is equivalent to `undefined`, which in turn evaluates to true.

And *that* is the reason, why the form is always submitted and is independent of sending the request synchronous or not.

If you want to submit the form only, when the response is `"Successful"`, you must return `false` from `ajaxSubmit` and then submit the form in the `success` function, as @halilb already suggested.

Something along these lines should work

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkpass.php",
        data: "password="+password,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == "Successful")
            {
                $('form').removeAttr('onsubmit'); // prevent endless loop
                $('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This has been removed from recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: @Archer From the manual: "false with **jqXHR** ($.Deferred) is deprecated".

Comment: On doing that, the submit button shows clicked and the page hangs.  maybe the form gets submitted again and again. when i alert something inside successful if block, it gets alerted again and again. recursively.

Comment: @user1865933 Ok, I missed that. When the form is submitted from the `success` function, `ajaxSubmit` is called again. Removing the `onsubmit` attribute should prevent this, however. Please try again.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche: You were spot on. I set a variable to 1 inside success function upon successful. And checked its value out of success function, if it was 1 outside the success function, then i wrote 'return true', else 'return false'. And that worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Used async: false instead of async: "false" and it worked.

Comment: $('form').submit();  didn't worked for me. Used id instead.

Answer (score 6):

It's as simple as the one below, and works like a charm.

My solution perfectly answers your question: How to make JQuery-AJAX request synchronous

**Set ajax to synchronous before the ajax call, and then reset it after your ajax call:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});

$ajax({ajax call....});

$.ajaxSetup({async: true});
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: "false",
        url: "checkpass.php",
        data: "password="+password,
        success: function(html) {
            var arr=$.parseJSON(html);
            if(arr == "Successful") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });


$.ajaxSetup({async: true});
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Although this is a handy way to set the default parameters for the AJAX call, it misses the actual error entirely and results in an unnecessary workaround. The `async` parameter takes a boolean, not a string. Changing it to a boolean is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding onSubmit event, you can prevent the default action for submit button.

So, in the following html:

```
<form name="form" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type='submit' />
</form>​
```

first, prevent submit button action. Then make the ajax call asynchronously, and submit the form when the password is correct.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit when button is clicked

    var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkpass.php",
        data: "password="+password,
        success: function(html) {
            var arr=$.parseJSON(html);
            var $form = $('form');
            if(arr == "Successful")
            {    
                $form.submit(); //submit the form if the password is correct
            }
        }
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: @halib: the above method works. ive tried. but i dont want to resort to this way. cant we achieve this by the default onsubmit event?

Answer (score 1):

I added dataType as json and made the response as json:

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>$res)); //send the response as json **use this instead of echo $res in your php file**
```

**JavaScript**

```
  var ajaxSubmit = function(formE1) {

        var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: "false",
            url: "checkpass.php",
            data: "password="+password,
            dataType:'json',  //added this so the response is in json
            success: function(result) {
                var arr=result.success;
                if(arr == "Successful")
                {    return true;
                }
                else
                {    return false;
                }
            }
        });

  return false
}
```

Comment: The `async` parameter takes a boolean, not a string. The string `"false"` actually gets cast to `true` because the string is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

The below is a working example. Add `async:false`.

```
const response = $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    async:false, 
                    url:"your-url",
                    data:{"data":"data"}                        
                });                   
 console.log("response: ", response);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

the solution is, work with callbacks like this

```
$(function() {

    var jForm = $('form[name=form]');
    var jPWField = $('#employee_password');

    function getCheckedState() {
        return jForm.data('checked_state');
    };

    function setChecked(s) {
        jForm.data('checked_state', s);
    };


    jPWField.change(function() {
        //reset checked thing
        setChecked(null);
    }).trigger('change');

    jForm.submit(function(){
        switch(getCheckedState()) {
            case 'valid':
                return true;
            case 'invalid':
                //invalid, don submit
                return false;
            default:
                //make your check
                var password = $.trim(jPWField.val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: "false",
                    url: "checkpass.php",
                    data: {
                        "password": $.trim(jPWField.val);
                    }
                    success: function(html) {
                        var arr=$.parseJSON(html);
                        setChecked(arr == "Successful" ? 'valid': 'invalid');
                        //submit again
                        jForm.submit();
                    }
                    });
                return false;
        }

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
var ajaxSubmit = function(formE1) {

            var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: "false",
                url: "checkpass.php",
                data: "password="+password,
                success: function(html) {
                    var arr=$.parseJSON(html);
                    if(arr == "Successful")
                    { 
                         **$("form[name='form']").submit();**
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {    return false;
                    }
                }
            });
              **return false;**
        }
```

Comment: Sure. Il check and let you know in a minute

Comment: It works only if password is incorrect. On entering current password, the submit buttons remains clicked. And the page stops responding

Comment: i hope u remove the ** in code. can you alert inside successful condition?

Comment: yes ive removed ** in code.when i put the alert code inside successful if block, the alert showed up but it always kept on showing up again and again. On clicking ok, it shows again and so on. recursively. maybe the form gets submitted again and again

Comment: okay,for testing purpose can yoy remove async: "false" from code and also use exit(); at end of php file.

Comment: Still the same behaviour after removing async:false and adding exit() at end of php file

Comment: hey remove var arr=$.parseJSON(html); from code and use html==Successful in the code.bcoz you are not passing json value from php

Comment: Tried that. Same behaviour

Comment: `async` takes a boolean, not string, see this comment on another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous?answertab=trending#comment78177658_13972378

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxSubmit = () => {
  var password = $.trim($('#employee_password').val());
    
  ajaxsync(password, (value) => {
    if (value) {
      alert(`user Login`);
    } else {
      alert(`user not Login`);
    }
  });
}

var ajaxsync = (password, callback) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkpass.php",
    data: "password="+password,
    success: function(html) {
      var arr = $.parseJSON(html);
      if (arr == "Successful") {
        callback(true);
      } else {
        callback(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.