# jQuery - JS - submit form in iframe and hide page animation loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser, submit

Ok my code is as follow:

```
<body>
<iframe>
<script>
$(function( {
 $('form).submit();
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="file" name="myfile"/>
</form>
</iframe>
</body>
```

this is an iframe inside another page  which has a **form with upload files** inside submitted via jQuery.

Now i'm wondering if it's possible to hide the page loading when the form is submitted, since i'm into another page and not into the iframe page directly.

[image]

> ^ remove this animation from browser when iframe form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done but instead you submit the form you should call post service from jquery to hide loding on page

Comment: are you talking about using Ajax? i can't use ajax, i can only submit form sync not async

Comment: check i edited my example, i have file inputs inside the form so i can't use ajax to send them

Comment: you should set your return value to false in ajax call.. this link may help your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous

Comment: i 'm not using Ajax, i'm submitting form using submit()

Comment: and i can't use ajax with input file

Comment: you don't want to use ajax or you can't send file with ajax?

Comment: i can't send file via Ajax

Comment: can i send files sync with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Your script inside the iframe, should be:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit();
});
```

*That wouldn't have executed otherwise.*

The way you are using text inside the frame, is for when Javascript is disabled on the client.

You can come across some problems also with frames. Can you not load the page contents into a DIV?

Comment: i wrote the iframe content in the example, in reality i add an src="" attribute to the iframe to load the source content, and my code alrady looks like you showed above ;)