# My For loop is too fast and I miss getting critical data

Tags: javascript, json, loops

The API i'm using to get JSON data only lets you put in a single date, and they don't have any methods for getting multiple dates. Therefor, I decided to create a `for` loop to loop through some dates, to pick up all the json data I need. The problem is, the loop does not wait for the json file to return the data, so even though I get some of the data, I don't get all of the data. What is worse, is some dates are slow to come back, so they don't even get pushed into the array in the right order. It just pushs them in, in a somewhat random fasion. How can I tell the loop to "wait" until I get the data, until looping again?

```
jsonDataArray = [];
    for (var k = 10; k < 20; k++){
        var num = k;
        var n = num.toString();
        var mydate = "2017-02-"+n; 
        d3.json("http://api.fixer.io/"+mydate, function (jsonData) {
            jsonDataArray.push(jsonData);   
        }
    )}
```

Comment: Since you have to wait for the result to come back for the next one, you basically want a recursive function. Pass in a start, pass in an end. If start < end, call self again with an incremented start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make JQuery-AJAX request synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous)

Comment: This isn't a AJAX request.

Comment: @Shawn - It's the same principle tho - making async requests in order.

Comment: @Shawn, yes it is, d3.json() makes an ajax request using the url that you pass

Comment: @tymeJV No, you don't need to wait for the next one.. each call is not dependent on the previous call. Why slow your program down when you can make multiple requests at once?

Comment: @BrianGlaz - Yeah, you're right. My bad :)

Comment: @tymeJV You just can't use push, and should assign directly to an index. `jsonDataArray[k] = jsonData;` for example. Promise approach is better though, so you actually know when all requests are complete.

Comment: @BrianGlaz - Yep, OP would have to use `let` tho in the loop, else `k` is always going to be the final loop counter. I like the promise solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [d3.promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3.promise) *(3rd party module)* and [d3.range()](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#range)

```js
Promise.all(
  d3.range(10, 20)
    .map(day => d3.promise.json("http://api.fixer.io/2017-02-" + day))
).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3.promise@2.0.0/dist/d3.promise.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still running into issues of getting the complete data, for example: a month, but this little code does what its intended to do, which is pull every single data I requested without missing any or putting the dates in random order in the array. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I/O in JavaScript is non-blocking, so data will be returned in your callback handler after your loop is done.

You could return an array of Promises from your loop and then use  `Promise.all`.
Here's the idea:

```
results = [];
for (var k = 10; k < 20; k++){
        var num = k;
        var n = num.toString();
        var mydate = "2017-02-"+n;
        results.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          d3.json("http://api.fixer.io/"+mydate, function (jsonData) {
              resolve(jsonData);
          }}));
    )}  

Promise.all(results).then(function (jsonArray) {
    ... work on the jsonArray
}
```

Comment: Your callback is wrong. You're resolving to the error messages, not the data.

Comment: you mean the d3 callback?

Comment: Oh my. Didn't know that one. I'd never put something like that into a lib. You can not rely on *Function#length* in JS.

Comment: to be fair, I didn't either. I assumed the OPs code was correct for that part