# Why javascript variable isn't updating value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update the `flag` variable value when there is an error but it doesn't update even when there is error:

```
var flag = 0;
            var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
            // Validate User/Client Data When Next Button is clicked (Up or DOWN)
            if(index == 2){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('quiz-client-details'); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#signup-form').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.status == 'success') {
                            console.log(data.status);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        $('.error-box').html(data.responseText);
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                });

            }
            index++;
            console.log(flag);
```

I'm trying to update flag value here:

```
error: function(data){
                        $('.error-box').html(data.responseText);
                        flag = 1;
                    }
```

But in console the `flag` value is 0!

Thanks

Comment: Hi.

I think there is a 0 at the console because you execute an AJAX (Asynchronous !!), so the code execute

console.log(flag);

Before get the result of the AJAX.

Comment: You are using console before the completion of the request....

Comment: Ajax call is not blocking

Comment: @Víctor so what's the solution buddy?

Comment: Use the parameter  async: "false",

There is more info in other thread like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous