# Pass data to sling model

Tags: json, rest, aem, sightly, sling-models

Is it possible to pass a string or data that is retrieved in an Ajax call to sightly html?
I have a 3rd party response in Ajax but I am trying to make the html look prettier by not using script tags. Hence I am planning to write pojos. But the call to the 3rd party will be an Ajax call. Is there a way to bind the Ajax response to sightly html ?

Comment: Implement a clientlib, that's more straight forward and does not require the roundtrip to the publish instances. Otherwise you have to request a resource with the dedicated resource type and pass the params to the path for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the ajax inside the JavaScript Use API.

```
<sly data-sly use.data1='getAjaxResponse.js'/>
```

Then pass the response to the model

```
<sly data-sly-use.sampleModel="${'com.project.SampleModel' @data1=data1}"/>
```

The below code JavaScript is not [synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous#:%7E:text=Set%20ajax%20to%20synchronous%20before,ajaxSetup(%7Basync%3A%20true%7D)%3B), so that needs to be [handled separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971769/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-synchronous#:%7E:text=Set%20ajax%20to%20synchronous%20before,ajaxSetup(%7Basync%3A%20true%7D)%3B)

getAjaxResponse.js

```
use(function() {
    let result;
    $.ajax({url: "/path/to/ajax/", success: function(response){
        result = response;
    }});
    return result;
}
```

SampleModel.java

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class SampleModel{

    @Inject
    private String data1;
}
```